# Regular expressions in a Bash case statement

Tags: regex, bash, case, glob

I am using following script, which uses case statement to find the server.

```
    #!/bin/bash
SERVER=$1;
echo $SERVER | egrep "ws-[0-9]+\.host\.com";
case $SERVER in
ws-[0-9]+\.host\.com) echo "Web Server"
;;
db-[0-9]+\.host\.com) echo "DB server"
;;
bk-[0-9]+\.host\.com) echo "Backup server"
;;
*)echo "Unknown server"
;;
esac
```

But it is not working. Regex is working with egrep but not with case. sample O/P

```
./test-back.sh ws-23.host.com
ws-23.host.com
Unknown server
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 67):

Bash case does not use regular expressions, but [shell pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) only.

Therefore, instead of regex `ws-[0-9]+\.host\.com` you should use pattern `ws*.host.com` (or `ws-+([0-9]).host.com`, but that looks a bit advanced and I've never tried that :-)

Comment: Thank you @glenn_jackman. On some machines (CentOS 7.3 with bash 4.2.46(1)) I was getting syntax errors "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"  for pattern +([a-zA-Z0-9])=*. On a fc19 bash version 4.2.53(1) machine no syntax error - extglob was set by default.

Comment: @gaoithe Thanks for this comment! I had a +() construction in a case statement, and interactively it worked but in a bash script the syntax was refused. I didn't understand it until I found your comment. When I switched on extglob in my script, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 19):

For reference, however this is already mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9631449/5782849), from `man bash` Pattern Matching section provide rules for composite pattern creation as:

> Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>   
>   ?(pattern-list)
>           Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
>   *(pattern-list)
>           Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>   +(pattern-list)
>           Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>   @(pattern-list)
>           Matches one of the given patterns.
>   !(pattern-list)
>           Matches anything except one of the given patterns.

*However using these extended pattern matching require `extglob` shell option to be enabled.*

Here is example of code for current problem:

```
shopt -s extglob;
SERVER="ws-45454.host.com";
case $SERVER in
        ws-+([0-9])\.host\.com) echo "Web Server"
                ;;
        db-+([0-9])\.host\.com) echo "DB server"
                ;;
        bk-+([0-9])\.host\.com) echo "Backup server"
                ;;
        *)echo "Unknown server"
                ;;
esac;
shopt -u extglob;
```

also, this: `shopt | grep extglob` can be used to check for its default value.

Comment: You can use just `shopt extglob` to see if it's set, no need for `grep`.

Comment: You don't have to escape the dot.

Comment: Oh how I wish it was just a standard regex.

Answer (score 18):

If you want assert that `*` really matches digits in `ws*.host.com` and want to use `case` instead of `if`, `elif`, `elif`...
you can use something like that:

```
case $SERVER in
  ws-[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789].host.com) echo "Web Server" ;;
  db-[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789].host.com) echo "DB server" ;;
  bk-[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789].host.com) echo "Backup server" ;;
  *) echo "Unknown server" ;;
esac
```

But that does not work for more than 999 servers.

If I had to make a script for this use case, I probably write something like that (because I love regexes and case syntax ;) ):

```
srv=`expr "$SERVER" : '^\(db\|bk\|ws\)-[0-9]\+\.host\.com$'`
echo -n "$SERVER : "
case $srv in
  ws) echo "Web Server" ;;
  db) echo "DB server" ;;
  bk) echo "Backup server" ;;
  *) echo "Unknown server !!!"
esac
```

Comment: The criteria of `case ... esac` can also be written as `ws-[0-9][0-9][0-9].host.com)`.

Comment: You could also use [:digit:] instead

Answer (score 13):

`case` can only use globs. If you want to do regex matching then you'll need to use a series of `if-then-else-elif-fi` statements, with `[[`.

Comment: How ? [[ws-[0-9]+\.host\.com]]) echo "Web Server" :- not working

Comment: Ignacio meant use `[[` in a cascading `if ... elif ... fi` statement

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a rather old question and my solution isn't much different from what [@syjust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2440698/syjust) has already provided, but I wanted to show that you can do just about anything at the matching stage in a `case/esac` statement.

```
$ cat case.sh && echo -e "#################\n" && bash case.sh ws-23.host.com
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=$1;
echo $SERVER | egrep "ws-[0-9]+\.host\.com";
case $SERVER in
  $(awk '{a=0}/ws-[0-9]*.host.com/{a=1}a' <<<${SERVER}))echo "Web Server";;
  $(awk '{a=0}/db-[0-9]*.host.com/{a=1}a' <<<${SERVER}))echo "DB Server";;
  $(awk '{a=0}/bk-[0-9]*.host.com/{a=1}a' <<<${SERVER}))echo "Backup Server";;
  *)echo "Unknown server";;
esac

#################

ws-23.host.com
Web Server
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but why not just `$(awk '/ws-[0-9]*.host.com/' <<< ${SERVER})`? There does not seem to be a need for the `{a=0}` and `{a=1}a`

Comment: I most likely copied that from another script I used - and now that I think of it, I have no clue why I even have it in that one.  Bad habits I guess.  Thanks for pointing it out.  It doesn't change the end result, other than wasted keystrokes - 33 of them - :(!

Answer (score 7):

Here’s an example of how to use the [elif](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html#sect_07_02_02) construct.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=$1;
regex_ws="^ws-[0-9]+\.host\.com$"
regex_db="^db-[0-9]+\.host\.com$"
regex_bk="^bk-[0-9]+\.host\.com$"
if [[ "${SERVER}" =~ $regex_ws ]]; then
  echo "Web Server"
elif [[ "${SERVER}" =~ $regex_db ]]; then
  echo "DB server"
elif [[ "${SERVER}" =~ $regex_bk ]]; then
  echo "Backup server"
else
  echo "Unknown server"
fi
```

I find it most reliable to store the regular expressions in their own variables.

Comment: Clean solution, thx

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `expr` to do the matching; it provides a grep-like regular expression syntax that should be robust enough for this application.

```
#!/bin/bash

server=$1
if   expr "$server" : 'ws-[0-9]\+\.host\.com' >/dev/null; then echo "Web server"
elif expr "$server" : 'db-[0-9]\+\.host\.com' >/dev/null; then echo "DB server"
elif expr "$server" : 'bk-[0-9]\+\.host\.com' >/dev/null; then echo "Backup server"
else echo "Unknown server"
fi
```